# focus filtering select on page load

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, dojo, setfocus

why does the following code don't focus the filteringselect?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
            @import "http://yandex.st/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    dojo.require("dijit.form.FilteringSelect");

    dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
        dijit.byId('dept').focus();
    });

    -->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
    <select name="dept" id="dept" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="test">test</option>
        <option value="test1">test1</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried it with ie7 and firefox 3/4 - it works.
but it fails in ie8 :-(
may this be a dojo bug - or am I doing something wrong?
when does dojo.addOnLoad() fire? after the DOM is ready, or after all widgets have properly been initalized?
regards
 gerhard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very intresting bug.. i have made small research and found solution. maybe it looks like a "dirty hack", but still it can help you.

you can simply add timeout:

```
dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
        setTimeout(function () { dijit.byId('dept').focus() }, 400);
});
```

Not noticeable by a user but it gives IE a moment to breathe.

[It's work in IE8 for me](http://pastehtml.com/view/1e1upel.html)

Comment: Interestingly, when I try this it seems like even setting 0 as the timeout works - which suggests that simply deferring this line of code until after the ready process completes is enough.  Not sure why this is necessary (and seemingly ONLY in IE 8 specifically); to answer Gerhard's question, addOnLoad/ready callbacks are executed after (1) the DOM is ready (or `window.onload` in IEs that don't support `DOMContentLoaded`), (2) all `dojo.require`d modules to that point are loaded, AND (3) if `parseOnLoad` is true, the parser has run and widgets are started up.

Comment: further research yesterday brought me to the same conclusion. i'll search dojo-trac for a simmilar bug, or file a new one!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what browsers fully support this, but you could try:

```
<select name="dept" id="dept" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect" autofocus>
```

Also, I don't see why you're using an `Import` statement if you could just use the link tag:
**Before:**

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "http://yandex.st/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";
</style>
```

**After:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yandex.st/dojo/1.6.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
```

Comment: I doubt `autofocus` will have an effect, since this `select` tag will end up replaced by a FilteringSelect widget, which doesn't recognize any `autofocus` attribute.